# Shopify command npm create @shopify/hydrogen@latest facing error after update

Tags: shopify, shopify-hydrogen, shopify-cli

While running this command, I'm getting such a popup to [Upgrade available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2ggy.png)  and after answering the script prompt questions about the app configuration. I get the npm package installation error as below.

```
  npm ERR! Found: @remix-run/react@1.17.1                                                                                             │
```

│      npm ERR! node_modules/@remix-run/react                                                                                              │
│      npm ERR!   @remix-run/react@"1.17.1" from the root project                                                                          │
│      npm ERR!                                                                                                                            │
│      npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:                                                                                              │
│      npm ERR! peer @remix-run/react@"1.19.1" from @shopify/cli-hydrogen@5.1.1                                                            │
│      npm ERR! node_modules/@shopify/cli-hydrogen                                                                                         │
│      npm ERR!   @shopify/cli-hydrogen@"^5.1.0" from the root project

This is what I'm facing.

To resolve this error, try the below steps.

Ignore the peerDependencies by --legacy-peer-deps flag
Clear npm cache
Downgrade the npm version from 7.x to 6.x
Remove node_modules and package.json. Then run npm install.

It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily resolve this, I have updated the package.json manually.

1. "@remix-run/react": "1.17.1" => "@remix-run/react": "1.19.1"
2. "@shopify/cli-hydrogen": "^5.1.0" => "@shopify/cli-hydrogen":
   "^5.1.1"